# Query to remove trailing or leading space from middle of the string using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, trim, sql-server-2017

I have a column with data as given below -
[image: BEFORE]

I want to remove any [space] before and after the first instance of the '-' character in the data so that I can get the following cleansed data -

[image: AFTER]

How to write this as a SQL Query ?

Comment: You mean `B20 - 86..` become `B20-86..`?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Does it always start with 3 charcters?

Comment: No...that is why it is necessary to look for the first instance of hyphen '-' and remove any space before or after it.

Comment: Do you want to keep instances after the first '-' that have a space around them?   Meaning  "ABC - ABC - DEF" becomes "ABC-ABC - DEF" and not "ABC-ABC-DEF"

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
CREATE TABLE Spaces(
  Value VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO Spaces VALUES
('B2555 - 30...'),
('Babc30 - 40 ...'),
('B5- 50..'),
('B6AfG066ML -60..');


SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' -', Value) > 0 THEN
            STUFF(Value, CHARINDEX(' -', Value), 1, '')
            ELSE
            Value
            End Result
FROM
    (
      SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('- ', Value) > 0 THEN
                  STUFF(Value, CHARINDEX('- ', Value) + 1, 1, '')
                  ELSE
                  Value
                  End Value
      FROM
          (
            SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' - ', Value) > 0 THEN
                        STUFF(Value, CHARINDEX(' - ', Value), 1, '')
                        ELSE
                        Value
                        End Value
            FROM Spaces
          ) T1
    ) T2;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------------------+
|         Result         |
+------------------------+
| B2555-30- ABC - ABC... |
| Babc30-40 ...          |
| B5-50..                |
| B6AfG066ML-60..        |
+------------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7876ee8a48dd514eaee139d23a1ebbfa)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a another option for you.

This is assuming the following:

- Only remove lending or trailing space around the first instance of '-', all others are to be preserved.
- Only accounts for 1 and only 1 leading or trailing space.
- Could have already "cleaned" data.

Give this a try:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [StringData] NVARCHAR(100)
    );


INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [StringData]
                      )
VALUES ( 'ADFADSF- ASDFSADF - Q343243498' )
     , ( 'ABC - EFSSADF - 2345234532' )
     , ( 'EFGSADFSA -ASDFSADF - 2342345234' )
     , ( 'ASDF34 - ASDLFASDJF - 234234 - 34324' )
     , ( 'ABC-123 - 465 - 685' );

SELECT *
     , STUFF([StringData]
              , CHARINDEX('-', [StringData]) - 1
              , 3
              , REPLACE(SUBSTRING([StringData], CHARINDEX('-', [StringData]) - 1, 3), ' ', '')
            ) AS [CleanStringData]
FROM   @TestData;
```

Basically what this does is strip 1 character before '-' to one after out, replacing that will those same character but with spaces removed if they exists.